# Сравнение списка списков в python

Tags: python-3.x, list, сравнение

## Сравнение нескольких списков (более 2-х)

Имеется список списков

```
all_list = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 4, 2, 1], [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 4]]
```

необходимо сравнить все списки и вывести одинаковые значения которые имеются во всех списках в отдельный список, в данном примере это

```
list_a = [1, 2, 4]
```

Обычно для сравнения двух списков использую

```
set(list_1).intersection(list_2)
```

но как сравнить несколько списков (более 2-х, в моем случае более 100)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set(all_list[0]).intersection(*all_list[1:])
```

или

```
set.intersection(*(set(elem) for elem in all_list))
```

---

*Объяснение:*

Метод `.intersection()` может принимать *любое количество* аргументов.

Звездочкой перед списком (в первом случае) или перед генератором (во втором случае) сделаем из отдельных элементов *отдельные аргументы*.